# magento magento2 image slider from scratch

Tags: magento, slider, magento2

Was looking around for instruction on how to build simple image slider in magento 2. No fancy back end. Just some cms page code, block code and php. Simple. Can't seem to find anything. If anyone can explain or have a link for a good article, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. In fact, asking for links is explicitly off-topic here. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.magestore.com/banner-slider-on-magento2.html

Go to the link and download it free via registration process (like e-commerce order)

User Guide link

https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://www.magestore.com/media/productfile/b/a/banner_slider_magento2_userguide.pdf